# Reading diacritical marks from a file and inserting them to an XML

Tags: python, xml, io, diacritics

I'm currently trying to read names from certain files and insert them in an XML. All is going well until one of the names contains a diacritical mark, then that certain letter is inserted into my intermediary dictionary as `\xc4\x82C`, or something like that. More so, when I try to insert the word that had the diacritical sign, from the said dictionary, it signals an error:

> All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

So I take it neither Python nor XML like diacritics. My files all contain lots of diacritical signs and I'd rather avoid removing them as in my country some names are different only by a diacritic.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Which Python version and which XML toolkit are you using? Unicode handling differs wildly between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.8 and as for the XML toolkit I don't really know. I use LXML to read and write to the xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you load data from files into a Python 2.7 `str`. In Python 2.7 that is represented solely as bytes, there is no added information what characters those bytes should actually represent.

Your XML toolkit refuses to guess, it only accepts ASCII characters, where the mapping is pretty clear (i.e. bytes 0-127). So you have to decode your `str` into a `unicode` object:

```
ustr = data.decode(encoding)
```

You can then pass your new `ustr` to LXML. To figure out which encoding you need, you should look at your data. Depending on where in the world your data originates from, I'd start with a few guesses such as `'latin1'` or `'utf-8'`. You can try both and see which one gives the expected result.

If you are developing on Windows, it's best to do this in IDLE Python or another IDE, the Windows console is very limited when it comes to unicode.

Comment: Well basically I did this: student = etree.Element('student', OrderedDict([("nume",Studenti[key][0].decode("utf-8")),("prenume",Studenti[key][1].decode("utf-8")),("nr_matricol",str(key)),("medie",Studenti[key][2])])). I've put utf-8 because that is the file's enconding, from which I take the names. Now it signals me an error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 5: invalid continuation byte.

Comment: With "latin1" decoding it actually works, inly that it inserts diacritics like this \xc4\x82C instead of the diacritics

Comment: Apparently my encoding should be Windows-1250 or ISO 8859-2. Tried them both and it works only instead of the diacritics it put the character code.
For example: "BĂBĂIŢĂ" ->  "B&#196;&#8218;B&#196;&#8218;I&#313;&#728;&#196;&#8218;"